# Replicate Drupal form options as taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm moving a site from Drupal and wondering if Wordpress can build forms the same way.

I want the drop down menu options to be similar to this one's fragrance drop down, which has custom color swatches and calls an image change when selected. I'm guessing taxonomies are the way to go, but how do I write a taxonomy like this?

On the admin side, I'd like to list all the fragrances a company makes. Then, for each particular product, you can checkmark the scents attached to that product in a box similar to Categories. On the front end, it will output that image and scent as an interactive drop down.

Can Wordpress handle something this complex, are taxonomies the way to do it, and how do I approach it? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Would the variants be the same for every product? If not, I'm not sure it's the way to go

Answer (score 1):

They are using an asp element `comboboxContainer` ([src](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1list/default.htm?turl=XMLDocuments%2FReference%2Fhtml%2FEvents_T_C1_Win_C1List_ComboBoxContainer.htm)) so the only way to replicate that would be with jQuery.